# How to filter with comma separated variable in tabular DAX

Tags: dax, tabular

So basically my problem is about I am trying to filter with Current Office a person that may have more than one current office. I am passing IDs for current offices as a comma separated values in a variable then I need those values to filter by.

Here i posted an example when I have just one CurrentOfficeId but what if I have multiple ?

```
DEFINE 
    VAR CurrentOfficeIds = "2"

EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Person'[CurrentOfficeId],
    'Person'[Current Office Name],
    'Person'[Display Name],
    FILTER ('Person',[CurrentOfficeId] = VALUE(CurrentOfficeIds))
)
```

Multiple officeids

```
DEFINE 
    VAR CurrentOfficeIds = "2,3,4"

EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Person'[CurrentOfficeId],
    'Person'[Current Office Name],
    'Person'[Display Name],
    FILTER ('Person',[CurrentOfficeId] = ?????)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not precisely what you asked for but may work for your purposes.

You can define your variable as a comma-separated list and then just pass that in.

```
DEFINE 
    VAR CurrentOfficeIds = {2,3,4}

EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'Person'[CurrentOfficeId],
    'Person'[Current Office Name],
    'Person'[Display Name],
    FILTER ('Person',[CurrentOfficeId] IN CurrentOfficeIds)
)
```

If you are using an older version of DAX that doesn't support the `IN` functionality, then you can use `CONTAINS` instead of `[CurrentOfficeId] IN CurrentOfficeIds`:

```
CONTAINS(CurrentOfficeIds, [Value], [CurrentOfficeId])
```